# "identifier not found" in C

Tags: c, microcontroller

I'm currently programming a microcontroller (TM4C123GH6PM from Texas Instruments) with Code Composer Studion in C. For testing the code, I want to read out the voltage over a resistance. I have written this code and also checked it with an example by TI (which is pretty close to what I want to do).

In both cases, it is no problem to compile the code. But when I want to watch the expression ui32ADC0Value, Code Composer Studio shows before starting the code ui32ADC0Value = 0 with ui32ADC0Value as type unsigned int, but after starting the code it says "identifier not found" and suddenly the type gets unknown.

I can't explain that to me, because as I already said, I tried something quite similar with the code officially published by TI and in both cases the error appeared.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include"inc/hw_ints.h"
#include"inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include"inc/hw_types.h"
#include"driverlib/gpio.h"
#include"driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include"driverlib/timer.h"
#include"driverlib/interrupt.h"
#include<math.h>
#include<driverlib/adc.h>
#include<driverlib/timer.h>


void main(void)
{
    uint32_t ui32ADC0Value;

    // set system clock
    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_5|SYSCTL_USE_PLL|SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN|SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ);

    // activate ADC
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_ADC0);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOE);

    // assign ADC function to PIN PE2
    GPIOPinTypeADC(GPIO_PORTE_BASE,GPIO_PIN_2);

    // configure ADC
    ADCSequenceConfigure(ADC0_BASE,1,ADC_TRIGGER_PROCESSOR,0); // prozessor as trigger source
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE,1,0,ADC_CTL_CH1|ADC_CTL_IE| ADC_CTL_END); // scan AI1 /generate interrupt at the end /last step
    ADCSequenceEnable(ADC0_BASE,1); // activate ADC Sequence 1

    while(1){
        ADCIntClear(ADC0_BASE,1); // delete maybe existing ADC Interrupts
        ADCProcessorTrigger(ADC0_BASE,1); // start convertion
        while(!ADCIntStatus(ADC0_BASE,1,false)){} // wait for end of convertion
        ADCSequenceDataGet(ADC0_BASE,1,&ui32ADC0Value); // read value
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping me in advance.

Comment: Did you mis-type it? Aside: there is no "of course" about `ui32ADC0Value` being `0`. It is *uninitialised*.

Comment: I checked it twice, this is not the probleme...

Comment: What happens if you move the definition of `ui32ADC0Value` outside of `main`?

Comment: Try assigning it. Sounds like it's being optimized away.

Comment: I dont use that tool but I assume there is a build for debug option and build for release?  are you building for debug?

Comment: Does it work if you write `uint32_t ui32ADC0Value = 0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I define the variable outside of main, it works. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

Optimized code can make it difficult for the debugger to know how to track your variable value. Try debugging the function with optimizations disabled, or watch the disassembly while stepping to track the value at function call points, etc.

Comment: Another classic trick is to mark the variable in question as `volatile`, which has the side effect of preventing the optimizer from trying to optimize it away.

Comment: Optimizations are completely disabled, this does not help. If I mark the variable as volatile, the debugger shows the warning 'argument of type "volatile uint32_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "uint32_t *"'